# Navbar occupies snap scrollbar space

Tags: html, css, scroll, navbar, tailwind-css

I'm trying to build a page with snap scrollbar using Tailwind.
My goal is to have few slides which can be scrolled and a sticky navbar at the top.

Scroll with only slides works fine, however after adding a sticky navbar to the top I've noticed a problem.

- scroll preview notices navbar as additional space (a one more slide which cannot be accessed)
- when scrolling to the top a white space can be seen.

Tried using absolute positioning instead of sticky, but cannot  figure out how would i move the nav across pages.

Code example:

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="h-screen w-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-scroll">
    <div class="sticky w-screen h-screen top-0 left-0">
      <div class="w-screen h-[100px] bg-gray-400">Nav Bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-cyan-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-yellow-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-red-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-lime-400"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the height of the parent div of the div with Nav Bar as content.

```html
<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>

<body>
  <div class="h-screen w-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-scroll">
    <div class="sticky w-screen h-screen top-0 left-0 h-[0px]">
      <div class="w-screen h-[100px] bg-gray-400">Nav Bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-cyan-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-yellow-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-red-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-lime-400"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Nice catch, `h-[100px]` made the white space smaller, but setting it to `h-[0px]` made it disappear completely.

Comment: @ToJestKrzysio You're right, I didn't even notice that. I have now adjusted the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You are adding h-screen in a div enclosing navbar which causes the wite space to appear. You can remove the `h-screen` from line 6
 `<div class="sticky w-screen h-screen top-0 left-0">` .

```html
<head>
  <script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="h-screen w-screen snap-y snap-mandatory overflow-scroll">
    <div class="sticky w-screen top-0 left-0">
      <div class="w-screen h-[100px] bg-gray-400">Nav Bar</div>
    </div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-cyan-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-yellow-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-red-400"></div>
    <div class="snap-start snap-mandatory w-screen h-screen bg-lime-400"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```